# Cordova splash screen - run code after splash is hidden

Tags: cordova, delay, splash-screen

I'm building an app with Cordova and have managed to set-up splash screens on Android fine using:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
```

in my config.xml and this works perfectly. The splash screen is displayed for the 5 second duration specified then hides.

I have got the app set up to listen for the "deviceready" event in order to execute the rest of my code. Again, this works fine.

The issue is that "deviceready" doesn't seem to wait for the splash screen to be completed - *I am aware that this is probably normal behaviour*. Sometimes the splash is still visible whilst the rest of my app has continued until the 5 seconds is up.

**So what I want to know is; is there a way to execute code only after the splash screen has finished displaying for at least the defined duration?**

Perhaps there is another Cordova event that is raised?

** Side note - I do want to make this as cross platform as possible so I would prefer not to make Android specific fixes for this if at all possible. **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do use the cordova API to close the splash when you want.

Use a high value on XML configuration:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="60000" />
```

And in your JS:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
});
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution taking a little inspiration from @mharr's answer above. I displayed the splash as shown here with a really long `"SplashScreenDelay"` then used `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` to hide the splash after a timeout of a few seconds so that the splash was always visible for at least that long. It would be nice for the Cordova API to trigger some sort of "splashdelayover" event to listen for so that you can continue your app when both the device is ready **AND** the splash has finished. Otherwise being able to define a delay seems a little pointless to me. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to not depend on splash screen to be there or not.  If I want my image to show as a splash screen, and have code running behind it or depending on it, I put my splash screen image as my index.html page and code on that page, then jump/redirect/load the "first" page when my code wants to.  Then I just use a solid color image as a splash screen, for minimal time, as Apple still wants it there.